# Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi I have an error when I am trying to install and import expo-notifications. I followed the documentation here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/notifications/ and ran `expo install expo-notifications`  but I am receiving this error when I try to import it. I know the error comes from this import as when i comment it out, my app loads normally. I am using the expo managed workflow. Appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue! Edit: tested it on android simulator and it works there so this seems to be an IOS issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you try `pod install` ? 
Maybe the native module has not been installed

Comment: Are you using expo.io for development or react native cli? If you are using react native cli you can not use expo library untill you ejected from expo.

Comment: I don't have a podfile so i can't pod install, im using the managed workflow by expo.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get it working by upgrading from expo sdk 37 to expo sdk 38 by running `expo upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an open issue on Github. Try this:

1.delete node_modules & package-lock.json

2.`npm cache clean --force`

3.`npm install --save @react-native-community/push-notification-ios`

https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios/issues/43#issuecomment-625020674